# App crashing in an iPhone device

Tags: iphone, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created a sample application in IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 and added Android and iPhone environments.

If I test the app on iOS simulator then it is working fine but after installing  the app on an iPhone device sometimes it is getting crash on launch and sometimes it is working fine.

1. IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0
2. Xcode 6.2
3. iPhone device running iOS 8.2

Comment: Do you get a crash report?

Comment: No. If possible I will attach the logs.

Comment: Did you add any different  code in the app or is it just an empty hello world app ?

Comment: It's just an empty hello world app

Comment: Thanks for the contribution for all. As I commented earlier, I would have given the device log if there is any. I believe you can understand what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Provide crash logs from the device.
Provide your sample application.

I have run through multiple sample applications from the [IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0 Developer Center](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-all-tutorials-7-0/) and none of the apps crash my iPhone (running iOS 8.2).

Answer (score 0):

After several R&D, I have resolved the issue on my own by setting the deployment IOS target to 7.1 in XCode Project.

Earlier it was set as 7.0.